# On which layer is the data warehousing interface placed in the hexagonal architecture?

Tags: architecture, frameworks, domain-driven-design

[image]

As shown in the figure, following the hexagonal architecture pattern, the storage interface seems to be placed in the application layer. But according to the DDD specification, the data storage interface should belong to the domain layer. So what is to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Tseng in general. Note that the repository interface is a domain language-specific concept (it's in the **ubiquitous language** and **domain experts** must understand the meaning of each repository name and method). So it means it's a port that the domain layer exposes.

Can we use it in the presentation layer? Yes, but it's not recommended. We design an application layer to address some concerns (like opening db connections, starting and committing transactions, etc) that can be reused on many presentation layer methods (separation of concerns). The application layer exposes use case scenarios. The presentation layer initiates the application layer use cases.

In this picture, there are two kinds of repositories. One for the **write model** (commands that use the domain model) and another for the **read model** (queries that use another model named read model instead of the domain model to optimize queries).

So this sentence from @Tseng's answer is not quite right:

> What "Queries can bypass domain layer" means, is that you don't have
> to use domain or application services to access the repository

It means that queries (in the CQS/CQRS pattern) use the read model instead of the domain model. We don't use the domain repository in queries. So "**bypassing the domain layer**" means using another model for queries instead of the domain model.

Comment: I looked up some information and saw a blogger on the Baeldung website who argued that the repository interface is equivalent to a port in a hexagonal architecture, and the implementation of the interface will be at the infrastructure layer. In a hexagonal architecture, ports should be located in the application layer. But in a DDD design, the repository interfaces should be at the domain layer. So I don't have a straight answer to that yet. Can you give me a straight answer?

Comment: Yes, hexagonal architecture differs at some point from what DDD suggests. But you are the decision maker. So better look at the pros and cons of every decision you make rather than following instructions. Here is a good debate on the same subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72230883/ddd-repository-interfaces-in-domain-or-application-layer

Comment: We must understand different types of domain designs to decide which one to use. Here is a post to understand the domain's purity and completeness. https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/domain-model-purity-completeness/

Answer (score 0):

You got the answer already. The dependencies on the layers go from the outside to the inside. Since the implementations (!) of the data layer are on the right side in the infrastructure, it has an dependency to the core.

Your domain also needs access to the repositories, hence the interface goes to your core/domain, the **implementation** happens outside. You just have to take care not to put any types which are not in your core domain into the interface domains (such as `Entry<T>` of EF Core etc.).

Theres nothing wrong if the outer layers have a dependency (Repository interface) on the internal one, it still doesn't mean that the domain layer is used if you reference an interface from there. The the picture means with "Queries can bypass domain layer" (emphasis on "can", which is not "MUST") that it's fine to access the repository directly from i.e. your controllers w/o going through the domain. That is the case even if the interface is designed in the domain, after all, its just an interface.

What "Queries can bypass domain layer" means, is that you **don't have to use** domain or application services to access repository but can directly use the repository interface instead.